# How to keep css block in the same position on window resize?

Tags: html, css, css-position

So I have a block  and it should keep it's place and proportions to fit background so when I resize the window, the block resizes aswell but background and block do resize in different ways.

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background: url('../img/mainpage/555.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

a#easttoplink {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    left:40%;
    top:26.5%;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width:21.5%;
    height:4%;
}
a#easttoplink:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it that way:

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25%;/* half of #content height*/
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto;
}
#container:after {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Wrapper is a  outside the #container